# Monitor Network Traffic Mac

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, networking, monitor, traffic

I'm wondering how to go about monitoring network traffic on my Mac. 
Like the way activity monitor does it, showing the bytes / packets in and out.

I know it's a bit vague, but I'm unsure of the best place to start.

**EDIT: I'm wanting to do this in code, not use an existing piece of software.**

Comment: See the Mac OS X-related answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126790/how-to-get-network-adapter-stats-in-linux-mac-osx (i.e. use sysctl).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just found the open source project, [MenuMeters](http://www.ragingmenace.com/software/menumeters/). It's got exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: you just said that you want to do this in code and not existing tool/software.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to look into [programming with pcap](http://www.tcpdump.org/pcap.htm). That's the library which drives tcpdump.

Comment: @calmh: Post your solution as an answer then so he can accept it.

Comment: It's in the question linked in the comment above. No need to repeat what has already been well answered by someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Use tcpdump for quick-n-dirty low-level command-line monitoring, and [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) for the kitchen sink.

OTOH, if you just want to know the *number* of bytes/packets (as opposed to their contents), try [Net Monitor](http://homepage.mac.com/rominar/net.html), which is commercial, unfortunately.

Comment: I wrote my answer before the OP added the qualifier.

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of paid & freeware applications. But if you a command line person like me, Try this:

```
nettop //displays network usage per application with lot of details
nettop (press h) //displays help menu
nettop (press c) //collapse and display brief info on network usage
```