# Mac OS X: watch network traffic (f.e. handle loading url action in Google chrome)

Tags: c++, objective-c, macos, networking, sniffing

I need to sniff my traffic.

I've found some related posts:
[Monitor Network Traffic Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662332/monitor-network-traffic-mac)

[How to get network adapter stats in linux/Mac OSX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126790/how-to-get-network-adapter-stats-in-linux-mac-osx)

And I've had a look at the [MenuMeters project](http://www.ragingmenace.com/software/menumeters/)

But it implements only common information about traffic: amount 
of loaded bytes e.t.c

I am going to analyze source code of the [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/develop.html)

So I need to create a class that implements protocol:

```
@protocol NetworkMonitor

- (void)systemWillRequestUrl:(NSURL *)url;
- (BOOL)shouldSystemLoadUrl:(NSURL *)url;
// e.t.c.

@end
```

Could somebody give me information how can I do this,
or point me to some open source projects, sniffers or something like this?

Comment: The easiest (and that's still not easy) would be to use built-in libraries like libpcap.

Answer (score 0):

Can you build on top of nettop(command line utility). It provides lot of useful data that MenuMeter or Mac's Activity monitor doesn't provides.

```
nettop //displays network usage per application with lot of details
nettop (press h) //displays help menu
nettop (press c) //collapse and display brief info on network usage
```

[Further reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man1/nettop.1.html)