# How To Monitor Network Activity From Within App?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, netstat, cfnetwork

I'm trying to monitor network activity on my iPhone from within an app I'm developing.  Does iOS support a netstat-like command or something similar that can tell me what what inbound and outbound connections are active ?

Comment: no, with Deepak on that -> only thing you can do is monitor the celluar data connectivity state.

Thats Apple having its huge hold over what you can't do.

Comment: then how does this app work? http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/netstat/id400071873?mt=8

Comment: Very interesting indeed. How does http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/netstat/id400071873?mt=8 work?

Comment: There are more and more apps on the store that do this, I believe the answer is at a very low level after reading these questions: [Link1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126790/how-to-get-network-adapter-stats-in-linux-mac-osx) [Link2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4281531/monitoring-network-usage-excluding-local-traffic)

Comment: By using BSD's socket functions, pretty much like netstat is doing...

Comment: This question gets pretty close: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7946699/iphone-data-usage-tracking-monitoring

Comment: Check my question..it has sample code with answer :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19977759/network-activity-monitoring-on-iphone

Answer (score 11):

After some searching I found [Apple's code used for netstat](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/network_cmds/network_cmds-356.8/netstat.tproj/inet.c).

Everything you need in the `void protopr(uint32_t proto, char *name, int af)` function.

I tested on the device and `sysctlbyname("net.inet.tcp.pcblist_n",...)` works.

That should be all you need.

Comment: I found the code on the documentation and it looks very promising, I believe they calculate and the print using `printf(" %7.7s[%1d] %7.7s[%1d]", "rxbytes", prioflag, "txbytes", prioflag);` But I am not that fluent on C, do you know how to interpret the data returned by `sysctlbyname`?

Comment: Yes, I do know, but it's all in the Apple code I posted. If you want I can chat tomorrow and help you out with that.

Comment: I would very much appreciate chatting with you tomorrow, meanwhile I will do my best to work out all I can from the inet code, its really cool to find people willing to help online!

Comment: @Zebs Sure, I'll just invite you to a chat in these comments when I'm ready.

Comment: definitively! I can send you my gmail using twitter if you want to use google talk.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8642/discussion-between-fbernardo-and-zebs)

Comment: Can I get in on this convo?  I'm not that familiar with C either and have no clue how to implement this.

Answer (score 2):

I can't test this but from what I gather you will have to use `sysctl` in combination with `sysctlnametomib` or alternatively  [`sysctlbyname`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/sysctlbyname.3.html) for this:

```
sysctlbyname("net.inet.tcp.pcblist", ...)
```

and/or

```
sysctlbyname("net.inet.udp.pcblist", ...)
```

Comment: I have tried and I can call the function but I do not know how to interpret the data it brings back. The question is looking for kbs in and kbs out, do you know how the data should be interpreted?

Comment: @Zebs the question did not mention any kbs, it mentions active connections... I can't test this myself but I recommend that you take a look at the [source code of netstat](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/network_cmds/network_cmds-356.8/netstat.tproj/inet.c) which should give you a good idea on how to interpret the results...

Comment: You are absolutely right, that was my question and I assumed it was included in "Monitor Network activity" but you are absolutely right. I will deep dive into netstat to figure out how that data is interpreted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use burp suite for this purpose , By this you can inspect all the http data going through your phone.
You have to install this in your mac/ubuntu/windows machine, and then create a proxy server with help of this tool and then modify your wifi setting in iphone/android phone to use your pc as proxy , and then it will capture all the input/output traffic.

Read full instruction here - 
http://www.engadget.com/2011/02/21/how-to-inspect-ioss-http-traffic-without-spending-a-dime/