# phonegap - network usage statistics

Tags: android, iphone, cordova, phonegap-plugins

Can anyone suggest me an approach to get network usage statistics data (like total data usage sent / received from phone) and data usage per application(for all apps installed on a phone). i want this approach to be generic if possible for Iphone, Android, BlackBerry, Windows etc.
I have searched for an application (http://www.onavo.com/) which does the same for iphone and android; but i am not sure how.
Also I have tried "NetworkStats" for android, which serves this requirement but only for Android os 4.0 and greater.

I am looking for an api or any other approach available.
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

There is no general solution for all platforms available on phonegap.
You have to implement it as native code for each platform and link phonegap as phonegap plugin.

Comment: Yes Max, that is the reason why i am focusing on "Trafficstats" for android part, but my major concern is Iphone.. I am not an iphone developer so i dont know if such thing can be achieved for Iphone.

Comment: App asks to install proxy profile on iphone. Proxy profile - means that your iphone will not connect directly to servers but will connect to your proxy server. Your proxy server will analyze traffic, compress when possible or block. e.g. you can configure it to block ad network content or even worse replace ads to yours ads.

Comment: i guess this can be one way to do it or probably the only way to do it..i am not sure, i am actually looking for something like this [Stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134661/how-to-monitor-network-activity-from-within-app)..something inbuilt.