# Monitor Incoming Bytes OS X

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, osx-lion, packet-sniffers

I am building a network utility for OS X. I've gone through Apples documentation, but I cannot find the framework that allows my app to monitor incoming bytes. Can anybody point me in the right direction? Thank you for your time!

Comment: What do you mean by monitoring incoming bytes? Do you want to capture all incoming packets, and be able to display their contents? Or do you just want to get a count of incoming bytes (or bytes per second) to a network interface, so you can display performance metrics?

Comment: I'm just keeping track of data usage. I only need the packets to determine their size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get statistics on a network, you can use the [`sysctl` system call](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man3/sysctl.3.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/3/sysctl). This is fairly thinly documented; there's [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126790/how-to-get-network-adapter-stats-in-linux-mac-osx) on StackOverflow that gives a brief example, and for more detail, I'd recommend looking at the [netstat source code](http://opensource.apple.com/source/network_cmds/network_cmds-356.8/netstat.tproj/).

Answer (score 0):

I think for something like this could be done with

http://www.wireshark.org/ or http://www.tastycocoabytes.com/cpa/

In Linux you could simply listen to the file that is associated with your network card.

But I don't think this can be done an easy way on OS X. But indeed there must be some way, thinking of LittleSnitch.

Comment: Which file are you thinking of?  One of the files under `/sys/class/net/{interface}/statistics`, where {interface} is the name of the network interface for the network adapter?  If so, then Brian Campbell's answer applies - you use sysctl on OS X (and on other BSD-flavored OSes) to get those statistics (not as easy as reading a statistics file, but not too bad - as he says, see the `netstat` command source).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [libpcap](http://www.tcpdump.org/pcap3_man.html), which is a portable library for doing packet captures used by tcpdump, Wireshark, and more.  It's not an official Apple library, but it's BSD-licensed so you shouldn't have any problem using it.

Comment: Note that, while it's not an official Apple library, in that it wasn't created by Apple, it *is* a library that ships with OS X, complete with manual pages and header files.