# Getting lnk2019 VC++

Tags: c++, winapi

I am getting this error and I don't know why.
I would like to create a library to operate with WinPcap, and public some of their functions. I attach part of my code:

```
class WinPcap
{
private:
    bool discoverDone;
    std::list<Device> discoverDeviceList;    
    void Listen();    

public:
    WinPcap();
    ~WinPcap();

    //This process is bloking, remain throw it in a different thread.
    std::list<Device> Discover();

    static void GetHostMacAddress(UINT8* macAddress, int pointerSize);
};
```

And now I found this method to get the host mac address in c++:

```
void WinPcap::GetHostMacAddress(UINT8* macAddress, int pointerSize)
{
    IP_ADAPTER_INFO AdapterInfo[16];       // Allocate information for up to 16 NICs
    DWORD dwBufLen = sizeof(AdapterInfo);  // Save memory size of buffer

    DWORD dwStatus = GetAdaptersInfo(      // Call GetAdapterInfo
        AdapterInfo,                 // [out] buffer to receive data
        &dwBufLen);                  // [in] size of receive data buffer

    PIP_ADAPTER_INFO pAdapterInfo = AdapterInfo; // Contains pointer to current adapter info
}
```

I am getting the error in that function. But if I comment the GetAdaptersInfo function, I don't get it.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Did you link your program with the winsock library?

Comment: please post the full error message. It isn't clear which symbol is unresolved (probably GetAdaptersInfo, but message would help).

Comment: BTW, `GetAdaptersInfo` is Windows API call, and your question is tagged as `osx`. You might want to check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126790/how-to-get-network-adapter-stats-in-linux-mac-osx

Comment: Yes, sorry, I don't know how it got to it. It is WinApi yes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am slightly confused as your question is tagged as `osx`, but `GetAdaptersInfo` is Windows API call and you seem to be using Visual Studio.

If the question is mistakenly tagged as `osx`, you have probably forgot to link your program to `iphlpapi.lib`

If it is really meant to work on OS X, you might want to check these links:

- [How to get network adapter stats in linux/Mac OSX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126790/how-to-get-network-adapter-stats-in-linux-mac-osx)
- http://wxwidgets.info/cross-platform-way-of-obtaining-mac-address-of-your-machine/