# Retrieve network interface stats in macOS app

Tags: objective-c, bash, macos, networking, command-line-interface

I searched for a long time in Objective-C on how I could retrieve some stats for bytes in/out of macOS network interface and haven't found anything.

I thought about using command line, and find an OS stats on socket (maybe in sysctl) which I could use to make some math, but haven't found.
I tried to grep on nettop, but the way it's done in CLI is impossible to grep.

I just found 2 apps on AppStore which does't exactly this, showing bandwidth used in real time:
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/network-scanner/id1103147103?l=en&mt=12
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/network-inspector/id515794671?l=en&mt=12

I tried to use Activity Monitor and sample process to understand the call they do without success.

Any idea on how those two apps retrieve number of bytes in/out of network interface?

Comment: If it helps, this is for Linux : `ip --statistics link show eth3`

Comment: What about this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1385692/1187415 ?

Comment: This C code using sysctl works perfectly: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1385692/1143827